# Java: trouble adding items to ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>

Tags: java, arraylist, bit-manipulation, combinations

I'm trying to write a program in Java that will calculate all combinations of elements in an integer array (with 5 elements) and output these combinations to an ArrayList. I've included my code below.

I use bitwise operations to find the combinations. Each combination is constructed as an ArrayList(Integer), called "writeitem". I then want to store these in another ArrayList, called "master", which has to have the form ArrayList(ArrayList(Integer)). [for formatting reasons <> have to be replaced with (); they don't show up otherwise...]

The problem arises when attempting to save each combination to the "master" ArrayList. If you run the code below, the printf function will show that the combination is constructed correctly. However, once I ask for it to be "added" to "master", it doesn't seem to be appended to the end of "master". Rather, all of "master" is overwritten with i copies of the combination just constructed.

So, for example, if I call the function on [1,2,3,4,5], my "master" array ends up being 31 copies of [1,2,3,4,5] (the 31st combination to be found).

I imagine this has something to do with using nested array lists, and there's a better way to achieve what I want. But it's equally possible I am committing some other novice error.

```
static ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> master = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
public static void generatecombs(int[] x){

    ArrayList<Integer> writeitem = new ArrayList<Integer>(); //empty list to construct each comb

    for(int i=1;i<32;i++){

        writeitem.clear(); //clear before constructing next combination

        if((i & 1)>0){          //check if each element is present in combination
            writeitem.add(x[0]);
        }
        if((i & 2)>0){
            writeitem.add(x[1]);
        }
        if((i & 4)>0){
            writeitem.add(x[2]);
        }
        if((i & 8)>0){
            writeitem.add(x[3]);
        }
        if((i & 16)>0){
            writeitem.add(x[4]);
        }

        System.out.printf("The %dth combination is %s\n", i,writeitem);
        master.add(writeitem); //output constructed element
        System.out.printf("The collection so far is: %s\n", master);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the new inside the loop

```
static ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> master = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();

public static void generatecombs(int[] x){

    for(int i=1;i<32;i++){

        ArrayList<Integer> writeitem = new ArrayList<Integer>(); // new list to construct each comb
        if((i & 1)>0){          //check if each element is present in combination
            writeitem.add(x[0]);
        }
        if((i & 2)>0){
            writeitem.add(x[1]);
        }
        if((i & 4)>0){
            writeitem.add(x[2]);
        }
        if((i & 8)>0){
            writeitem.add(x[3]);
        }
        if((i & 16)>0){
            writeitem.add(x[4]);
        }

        System.out.printf("The %dth combination is %s\n", i,writeitem);
        master.add(writeitem); //output constructed element
        System.out.printf("The collection so far is: %s\n", master);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! And thanks to everyone for their answers, it works now, and I see what I did wrong.

Answer (score 0):

remove that clear() method.from for loop.after every iteration clear() is removing the values from arraylist
put you arraylist creation inside for.

Comment: No, the clear is necessary. Replace the clear by a new inside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Move the construction of `writeitem` inside the for loop. You don't want to re-use the same array.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be to clone when adding to parent list before you clear writeItem.

```
master.add(writeitem.clone());
```

Comment: NO, clone Returns a shallow copy of this LinkedList.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're getting 31 copies is because you're running through the for loop, wiping the `writeitem` array clean each time, adding to it, and printing it out while still in the for loop, which then repeats 30 more times, until i hits 32.

Remove `writeitem.clear();` and see how you get on with that

Comment: Thanks. That clarifies my error. I didn't realize that once "writeitem" is output to "master", it still known as "writeitem" WITHIN "master", and so modified each time.